# Why is the message "The global sbt directory is now versioned" in 0.13?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm pretty new to Scala and sbt and I get the message below every time I run `sbt`. The message itself pretty much makes sense but I can't figure out what to do to fix it.

I think I'd like to move my configuration to the place where it's expected to be but not sure if that will that mess things up. I cannot find any doc on how to change the `sbt.global.base` system property.

`The global sbt directory is now versioned and is located at /Users/justinhj/.sbt/0.13.
You are seeing this warning because there is global configuration in /Users/justinhj/.sbt but not in /Users/justinhj/.sbt/0.13.
The global sbt directory may be changed via the sbt.global.base system property.`

Comment: [There's an issue reported](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1427) to improve the message and guide people what needs to be done.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should move everything that is in `/Users/justinhj/.sbt` to a new folder `/Users/justinhj/.sbt/0.13` (mind the `0.13` subdirectory). That is the new sbt 0.13 folder naming scheme.

If you don't want to change your global config folder you can invoke `sbt` with modified global base parameter `sbt.global.base` as follows:

```
sbt -Dsbt.global.base=/Users/justinhj/.sbt
```

Take a look at this document for more explanations: http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Command-Line-Reference.html

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way to get rid of this error is to remove the `.sbt` directory in your Home Folder. When you run sbt again, the new folder is created in the correct format and the error goes away.